# Will bazel fetching as long as i configured my project?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-science, bazel

While using TensorFlow, i first run

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

And then i copy the folder of this project to another computer, and run the same command again, I saw it will fetching again, and it will waste my time.
Is there a solution to only fetching one time, even I copied to another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the [bazel remote cache](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html) also shares fetched objects.